# How to connect SQL with VB?

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I know connection of MS Access and VB. I don't know connection of SQL with VB. Please provide some code examples.

Comment: SQL Server?  MySQL?  PostgresSQL?

Comment: i use visual studio 2005.i don't know sql or mysql or postgresSQl.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming MS SQL and VB6, try this article:

[Connecting to a SQL Server database using ADODB](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/24677-connecting-to-a-sql-server-database-using-adodb/)

**Edit:** Whoops, assumed wrong.

You can also visit [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) for other connection strings, such as SQL 2005 and SQL 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some basic code using VB.NET that will open and close a connection to MSSQL:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Dim SqlConn As New SqlConnection
SqlConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
SqlConn.Open()
SqlConn.Close()
SqlConn.Dispose()
```

That should meet your request i believe. If it is indeed VB6, then it will be a completely different syntax.